# Is it possible to return rows as well as a count of rows from one PDO function?

Tags: php, pdo, count, prepared-statement

I would like to get both the count of rows returned as well as the actual rows both from one prepared PDO statement, is this possible?

I am using PHP 5+ and Mysql.

For example:

```
global $dbh
$query = "SELECT title, date, title, description
        FROM posts
        WHERE title LIKE '%foo%'
        ORDER BY date
        DESC";

$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt-execute();

$count = count($stmt->rowCount());
$searcharray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return array($count, $searcharray);
```

Comment: Some DBs (e.g. mysql) will return the total # of rows retrieved via rowCount(), but it's not universal behavior, and PDO can't do antyhing about that. you'd have to run *TWO* queries, one counting, one doing the actual fetches.

Comment: From your example, why not count the result of the `fetchAll` after that command instead of doing a `count` on `rowCount()`? The `rowCount()` typically returns the `affected` rows from an update/insert/delete query.

Comment: Won't count($stmt->rowCount()) always return 1?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that `rowCount()` doesn't apply to `SELECT`.

Comment: @jon if you want to make an answer I'll happily accept.

Comment: @crm Alright, made in to an answer. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per request, answer form. ^^

Change the code to something like:

```
global $dbh
$query = "SELECT title, date, title, description
        FROM posts
        WHERE title LIKE '%foo%'
        ORDER BY date
        DESC";

$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt-execute();

$searcharray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = count($searcharray);

return array($count, $searcharray);
```

The [`PDOStatment::rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) function returns the affected rows of an update/insert/delete statement.  Instead, do a count on the result of `fetchAll` as that will give an accurate count on the number of rows returned from a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an array of rows, you don't need the count. You can get it any time.
So, just return an array and then count when needed.